# Getting a null error trying to add objects into an arraylist (simple piece of code)

Tags: java, object, arraylist

currently getting the error "java.lang.NullPointerException: null" when attempting to add my Earthquake objects into my array list.

Note: I am using BlueJ to manually create and input values for my Earthquake(s).

Here is my earthquake class:

```
public class Earthquake {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private double magnitude;
    private int year;

    public Earthquake(double latitude, double longitude, double magnitude, int year)
    {

       // initialise instance variables
       this.longitude = longitude;
       this.latitude = latitude;
       this.magnitude = magnitude;
       this.year = year;

    }

    public void storeLat (double longValue)
    {
        longitude = longValue;

    }

    public void storeLang (double latValue)
    {
        latitude = latValue;

    }

    public void storeMag (double magValue)
    {
        magnitude = magValue;

    }

    public void storeYear (int yearValue)
    {
        year = yearValue;

    }

    public int getYear ()
    {
        return year;

    }

    public double getMag ()
    {
        return magnitude;

    }

    public double getLat ()
    {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLong ()
    {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

And here is my Observatory class which is used to create the array list and add the Earthquake objects:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Obersvatory {

    private String ObsName;
    private String ObsCountry;
    private int ObsStartYear;
    private double ObsLocation;
    private ArrayList<Earthquake> quakes;
     public Obersvatory()
    {
        this.ObsName = ObsName;
        this.ObsCountry = ObsCountry;
        this.ObsStartYear = ObsStartYear;
        this.ObsLocation = ObsLocation;
        ArrayList<Earthquake> quakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
    }

    public void addQuakes(Earthquake e)
    {
        quakes.add(e);  
    }

}
```

I'd be grateful on any fixes / tips :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by doing this

```
 ArrayList<Earthquake> quakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
```

your are creating local array list who's scope is limited to `Obersvatory()` function so just use it like this to initialize the global `private ArrayList<Earthquake> quakes;` list of class

```
quakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Observatory` class, you have 2 variables with the same name `quakes`. The global one is never initialized (it is `null`).

You can fix that by replacing

```
ArrayList<Earthquake> quakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
```

with:

```
quakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
```

Don't define a new variable, initalize the global one.

Comment: That should be obvious but I'm fairly new so didn't really understand. Thanks for the replies :)